# Simplification of rational function with Assume function

Tags: functions

I didn't manage to simplify this expression :

```
Simplify[Assuming[x > 0, -((2 Sqrt[x^2/(1 + x^2)^2])/x)]]
```

Do you have ideas why the simplification is not sufficient ?

Comment: You have to put the `Assuming` at the beginning.

Comment: Or give the assumption as the second argument of `Simplify` (and omit `Assuming`).

Answer (score 1):

The [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) goes inside the [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html)

```
Assuming[x > 0, Simplify[-((2 Sqrt[x^2/(1 + x^2)^2])/x)]]

(*   -(2/(1 + x^2))  *)
```

Or put the assumption inside the `Simplify`

```
Simplify[-((2 Sqrt[x^2/(1 + x^2)^2])/x), x > 0]

(*  -(2/(1 + x^2))  *)
```